# PHP: Dynamically setting values in an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called `$brand_terms`. I'm accessing two objects in this array. In this case 'name' and 'slug'. I'm then trying to set values of these objects in an associative array called `$values`. The code is below:

```
$brand_terms = get_terms("pa_brand");
$values = array(
    foreach ($brand_terms as $brand_term){
        $brand_term->name => $brand_$term->slug, 
    }
);
```

The problem I have is with the separator `,`.  So the comma at the end of `$brand_term->name => $brand_$term->slug,`. If the loop is at the last value in the array, the comma is not needed and the the code is broken. Is there a nice way to remove this comma from the last iteration of the foreach loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That syntax is completely wrong. You cannot have a loop within an array declaration.

Instead create the array, then push elements into it during the loop:

```
$brand_terms = get_terms("pa_brand");
$values = array();
foreach ($brand_terms as $brand_term){
    $values[$brand_term->name] = $brand_$term->slug; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, PHP doesn't really have any problem with an extra comma in the last element of an array.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the problem isn't at all with the `,` literal, in fact that isn't valid PHP. You can't have a `foreach` loop inside of an array declaration.

The best approach is to define the array and then loop through the `get_terms()` return value as follows:

```
$values = array();

foreach( get_terms('pa_brand') as $term )
{
    $values[$term->name] = $term->slug;
}
```